# Occasional ctypes error importing numpy from mod_wsgi django app

Tags: python, django, apache, numpy, ctypes

Here's the setup:

- Django (1.2) app on mod_wsgi that imports ctypes
- Python 2.6.5
- Apache 2.2.3
- SELinux disabled
- RedHat EL 5 64bit
- some of the file system is mounted over nfs

Occasionally, when I restart apache I get an import error when it's trying to import ctypes. Every incoming request fails with a 500 error. If I restart apache usually everything just starts working again.

Here's the stack trace of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/home/appfirst/django/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 80, in get_response
   response = middleware_method(request)

     -------------- A BUNCH OF DJANGO MIDDLEWARE STUFF HERE -------------

 File "/home/appfirst/django/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
   __import__(name)

 File "/home/appfirst/backend/backend/streamer/views.py", line 6, in <module>
   import appfirst.main.models as FEmodels

 File "/home/appfirst/frontend/appfirst/main/models.py", line 27, in <module>
   import numpy, math, mpmath

 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
   import ctypeslib

 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/ctypeslib.py", line 9, in <module>
   import ctypes

 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 546, in <module>
   CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(lambda: None)

MemoryError
```

I thought it might be related to this bug, but I have SELinux turned off which I thought would mean this case could never occur:

- http://bugs.python.org/issue5504

Any suggestions on how to reproduce it consistently and/or fix it? This is really stumping me!

Comment: Something preventing memory from being allocated PROT_WRITE and PROT_EXEC does seem like the most likely culprit, given where the backtrace terminates.  Are you sure there isn't something else on your system which could be providing such protection?

Comment: I have almost the same setup, same problem, except the error is consistent for me. Restarting Apache doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: We've basically gotten around the problem by just not using numpy. Since removing the numpy import, we haven't seen it again. We weren't using numpy for very much, so we just wrote our own replacement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've run into this bug too. In my case it occurs when I exec a Python script from within a PHP script running under Apache on a 64-bit Linux system. [The Python code being run is the front-end to a pypy sandbox.] The same bit of code works fine on a 32-bit system and even works fine when the PHP script is executed directly from the command line. My "fix" has been simply to comment out that line "CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(lambda: None)" in ctypes/**init**.py. It's the last line of the file and is preceded by the following comment, showing that the programmer doesn't understand what's going on, either!

```
# XXX for whatever reasons, creating the first instance of a callback
# function is needed for the unittests on Win64 to succeed.  This MAY
# be a compiler bug, since the problem occurs only when _ctypes is
# compiled with the MS SDK compiler.  Or an uninitialized variable?
CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(lambda: None)
```

Clearly there's a deeper problem somewhere in cpython, but the fix works for me.

Comment: Since that last posting there has been quite a big of discussion of the issue on https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=645193. At least in my case it seems the problem is that the default SELinux security settings prevent httpd from executing code within the /tmp directory tree, which ctypes apparently attempts to do. The above "fix" merely postpones the problem until something does actually need to use CFUNCTYPE. For instructions on how to configure SELinux to allow httpd to execute the required code, see the bugzilla link (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=645193).

Comment: I should have mentioned: if the fix in the previous comment doesn't solve your problem, search on "ctypes SELinux". There's plenty of discussion out there, e.g. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=582009

Comment: sorry for rehashing an old thread.  I'm running into this issue on numpy 1.21.2.  Unfortunately, I am unable to find `ctypes/init.py`.  I'm using Anaconda and the libs are installed to: `/opt/conda/envs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/`.  I've manually searched through the folders and used `grep`: `grep -ir CFUNCTYPE .` but I can't find the file and line to comment out.  Any possible tips on where else I might search under?  Thank you for your post 

Comment: ooops...I goofed.  The file is here: `/opt/conda/envs/venv/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py`
line 273
in case it can be helpful to others

Answer (score 0):

In case others happen to run into this issue, my fix was to upgrade from Python 3.7 to 3.8.

This offending line: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py#L273

Was removed in 3.8: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py#L261-L270

Hopefully, it can save someone the headache of trying to monkey patch `ctype/__init__.py` which was unsuccessful for me due to the way `conda pack` handles standard Python libraries.

Hope that helps

Answer (score -2):

Consider turning SELinux off.
It should solve the problem.