# Apache2 / Python CGI: ImportError on web access, but works from command line

Tags: python, apache, opencv, cgi

I have a python CGI script I'm trying to run cv2.py from on a shared host.  I have everything working in the command line but when I take it to CGI it gets an importerror at cv2.

This is a peculiar Apache installation because my Python version 2.7.2 is not the default Python version and all the site packages are installed in my user home directory.

Here is the code:

```
#!/path/to/bin/python
import cgi
import cgitb
import sys
version = sys.version
cgitb.enable()
path = sys.path
import os
import pwd
# import cv2  << this is the line that causes the error from the web

def get_username():
    return pwd.getpwuid( os.getuid() )[ 0 ]
print "Content-Type: text/html"
print
print "<h1>%s</h1>" % version
print "<h1>%s</h1>" % path
print "<h1>%s</h1>" % get_username()
```

The weirdest part is, that the username, path, and version that are running from the web server, are all exactly the same as those that come out running from the command line.  From the command line, cv2 can be imported and used as normal but from the web, the same file gets importError trying to import cv2:

```
    cv2 undefined
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import 
      args = ('numpy.core.multiarray failed to import',) 
      message = 'numpy.core.multiarray failed to import'
```

If I try importing numpy or Image (PIL) I get a memoryError instead:

```
<type 'exceptions.MemoryError'>: 
  args = () 
  message = ''
```

I am wondering if there are any other possible problems with configuration for the web server that would cause import errors, when everything works from the command line and appears to be configured exactly the same as the web which doesn't work?

Comment: Is the installed cv2 package directories and files searchable/readable to the user that Apache runs your CGI script? The MemoryError itself can also be because of SELinux being enabled.

Answer (score 0):

So I did a little deeper searching on the memoryError, and found this obscure solution by modifying ctypes/**init**.py that seems to have done the trick in this case:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6769624/895656

It seems to be a bug in the version of numpy 1.8.2