# Python3 import error while executing with PHP

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

I have a PHP script to execute a Python script.

I want to use for example numpy and other modules in my Python script.

But when I add `import numpy as np` or `import numpy` to my Python script. My output is empty and the python script stops working.

Below you find my scripts without the imports.

How can I import modules like numpy, pandas etc?

## Versions:

- PHP Version: 5.5
- Python Version 3.4

## index.php

```
// Execute Python Script
echo 'Output:<br />';
$command = escapeshellcmd('/var/www/html/python/test.py fileName1.txt');
$output = shell_exec($command);

// Output Python Script
echo $output;
```

## test.py

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

# Imports
import sys
print("\n".join(sys.path))
import pip


# Check Script Arguments
if len(sys.argv) == 2:

    # Show Arguments
    print(sys.version)
    print('Python File:', str(sys.argv[0]), '<br />')
    print('Upload File:', str(sys.argv[1]), '<br />')


    installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
    installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
         for i in installed_packages])
    print(installed_packages_list)

else:

    # Missing Arguments
    print('Missing Arguments');
```

## Result and Output:

```
Output:
/var/www/html/python /usr/local/lib/python34.zip /usr/local/lib/python3.4 /usr/local/lib/python3.4/plat-linux /usr/local/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 08:59:07) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)]
Python File: /var/www/html/python/test.py
Upload File: fileName1.txt
['nltk==3.1', 'nose==1.3.7', 'numpy==1.10.1', 'oauthlib==1.0.3', 'pandas==0.17.0', 'pip==7.1.2', 'pymysql==0.6.7', 'python-dateutil==2.4.2', 'pytz==2015.6', 'requests-oauthlib==0.6.0', 'requests==2.8.1', 'scikit-learn==0.16.1', 'scipy==0.15.0', 'setuptools==18.4', 'six==1.10.0', 'sklearn==0.0', 'textblob==0.11.0', 'twython==3.3.0', 'vadersentiment==0.5']
```

If I add `import numpy as np` or `import numpy` to my Python script it stops working and the output is empty.

How can I import modules like numpy, pandas etc.?

If I add `import numpy as np` to my Python script and run the Python file with command line its working. So what can the problem be?

```
python3 /var/www/html/python/text.py fileName1.txt
```

Comment: Some error could be raised in python. Try to add this to see the errors `import sys; sys.stderr = sys.stdout`.

Comment: @rraayy 1. What happens if you start interactive python from the command line (with just `python3` by itself and not `python3 /var/www/html/python/text.py fileName1.txt`) and then type `import numpy` (and press Return) in the interactive Python interpreter?
2. How are you running your script, if not from the command line?

Comment: I fixed it! It was a memory error in numpy. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762566/occasional-ctypes-error-importing-numpy-from-mod-wsgi-django-app/6769624#6769624

Thanks Delimitry

Comment: @rraayy, can you please look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35386387/run-python-script-through-php-on-browser . Badly stuck there. Seems same issue as yours.

Comment: I tried commenting out the line which was suggested in the link of your comment.But it's not working for me. Output is still empty for me.