# calling python script from php failing when import numpy

Tags: php, python, python-import

I have found a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720860/python3-import-error-while-executing-with-php?lq=1). However, it did not help me to resolve my problem.

Using a web server I am trying to call a python script from a php script. However, when I import the numpy library I only get a blank screen while I get the expected output 'help' without the 'import numpy' line. Notably, there is no issue when running it through a terminal instead of web server.

php script:

```
<?php
  $input = 'help';
  $output = exec("/usr/bin/python3.5 /path/test.py '$input'");
  echo $output;
?>
```

python script (here I have commented out an attempt to throw an error, but all I get is 'PATH':

```
import sys
# try: 
    # import numpy
    # print('done')
# except Exception as e:
    # print(e)

import numpy
foo = sys.argv[1]
print(foo)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It "seems to fail to import numpy". Why do you think that?

Comment: @klutt I edited the question to clarify. I get a blank screen when I include the 'import numpy' line instead of the expected output 'help'

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: I could not find an error log for that. None of the error logs that I checked had logged anything